# Rule-patterns used by (f)lexers

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

I walked through a number of lex files and in some I found some strange constructs regarding the usage of the square brackets. I would expect that inside square brackets it is possible to use other square brackets as follows (using `...` just as placeholders)

- ranges: `[...[a-z] ...]`, where `[a-z]` denotes again a range, like in the manual (https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns): `[[:alpha:][0-9]]`
- literal `[...\[...\]...]` where `\]` and `\]` mean that they should be taken literal.

The strange patterns I found are (a.0.):

- `[[][\t ]*` so in the part `[[]` a not escaped `[`
- `({UNQUOTED}|=|\[=*{UNQUOTED})({UNQUOTED}|[[=])* {` also an not escaped `[` but now followed by an equal sign (`=`)
- `[%&()*+,\-/:;<=>[\]^{|}~]` a not escaped `[` but an escaped `]`
- `[^ ':["?"]*` even some more characters following the not escaped `[`.

The question I have:

- is this behavior described somewhere?
- or is it an error (though flex 2.6.4 doesn't give a warning or error) ?

Comment: You have definitely uncovered a couple of errors in the documentation. The pattern `[[:alpha:][0-9]]` is certainly a typo. As written, it is highly misleading (but doesn't trigger an error); it's a pattern which matches two characters. The first is matched by a character class whose set contains `[:alpha:]`, the character `[`, and the range `0-9`. The second character is a literal `]`. Outside of a character class, the character `]` has not special significance (although the manual has another typo in which that is written `]]`).

Comment: Also, the flex documentation does not include the complete set of rules for deciding whether `-` or `]` is special inside a character class. That's covered in the Posix ERE documentation, but it's not referenced. (Although it is mostly implemented.)

Comment: Finally, the spirit of the Posix regex rules is that anything which could have an interpretation should be accepted, no matter how ridiculous that interpretation might be. For this reason, an unbalanced `)` in a Posix regular expression is treated as an ordinary character, just as the unbalanced `]`. A more sensible convention would have been to require these characters to be escaped and treat the unbalanced characters as errors, but that's not the convention adopted in the 1980s, so there's a lot of legacy code which uses it. There's also a lot of badly-written regexes in the world. Caution.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/478, indicating these documentation bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `[[][\t ]*` — the `[[]` part matches a character class consisting solely of `[`.  It could also be written `\[`.
- `({UNQUOTED}|=|\[=*{UNQUOTED})({UNQUOTED}|[[=])*` — the `\[` is equivalent to `[[]`.  At the end, there is `[[=]` which is a character class consisting of `[` and `=`.
- `[%&()*+,\-/:;<=>[\]^{|}~]` — inside a character class, `[` has no special significance (though the [POSIX regular expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) notations for collating elements, equivalence classes and character classes — such as `[[:space:]]` — complicate that discussion).  If you place `]` first (or immediately after the `^` that negates the character class), it stands for `]` rather than the end of the class.
- `[^ ':["?"]*` — the repeated `"` doesn't do anything useful; the rest is as usual.  That's zero-or-more repeats of any character other than a blank, single quote, colon, open square bracket, double quote, or question mark.

The notations are all direct consequences of the rules of how regular expressions are formed.

Comment: Also, outside of a character class `]` has no special significance.

Comment: From the third bullet: so in principle `[` a has no special meaning inside a `[..]` unless it is `[:alpha:]` or `[0-9]` (the later denoting a range). What about `[[:digit:][A-Zabc]]`  or `[[:digit:][ABCabc]]`? Would the later mean a digit `[`, `]`, `A`, `B`... `c`?

Comment: @albert: `[` only has significance inside a character class if if is part of a Posix named character class. `[0-9]` does not have a `[` with special significance, but the `]` will terminate the character class. (That is, the complete character class).

Comment: @albert — If you want a single character class with multiple parts, you can use (for example), `[[:digit:]A-Zabc[:punct:]]`. The outer set of square brackets delimits the entire class; the first element is the named character class for the digits; then you have the upper-case Latin alphabet, the first three lower-case letters of the Latin alphabet, and the punctuation characters. You can't enclose the `A-Z` in an extra set of square brackets.  If you used `[[:digit:][A-Zabc\]]` then you have digits, upper-case letters, lower-case 'a', 'b', 'c' and the square brackets `[` and `]` in the class.